# Как определить текущий url на nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Как на NodeJS определить текущий URL страницы?

[Конечно есть пример разбора заранее вписанного URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url), но охота считать URL тот, что в адресной строке. Если тема уже была прошу указать.

Сам пробовал так:

```
var url = require("url"); //текущий URL?
console.log(
    url.href + '\n' +
    url.protocol + '\n' +
    url.hostname + '\n' +
    url.port + '\n' +
    url.pathname + '\n' +
    url.search + '\n' +
    url.hash
);
//вывод undefined..
```

Comment: Речь о URL в контексте сервера? Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: ну, если языком PHP - речь о переменной SERVER )) Грубо говоря запустил я приложение по адресу http://localhost:8080/myapp?row=5 - вот всю эту строчку надо считать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере понятие "*Текущий URL*" лишено смысла.

В отличии от PHP, где каждый файл может обрабатывать запросы к отдельному URL в node.js существует всего **одно** централизованное приложение, которое обрабатывает запросы ко всем URL.  Никаких "суперглобальных" переменных содержащих "текущий URL" в node.js **нет и быть не может**: приложение может обрабатывать несколько запросов одновременно.

Если проводить аналогии с миром PHP, то это тот же принцип, что используется в Symfony: приложение получает объект запроса и должно вернуть объект ответа. При этом URL известен только в контексте запроса.

Исходя из вышесказанного, типичное node.js приложение-HTTP сервер (без использования сторонних библиотек) может иметь вид:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // Вывод URL к которому было произведено обращение
    console.log(req.url);

    // Отдача ответа.
    res.write('output');
    res.end();
});

server.listen(8000);
```

---

Что касается модуля `url` - то его цель предоставить вам средства для разбора некоторого, заранее известного URL.